# Changing TARGET of almost ready android app

Tags: android, api, dictionary, target

Starting the development of my android app,that uses Maps API, I didn't know that I must to set special TARGET for app "Google APIs". Now,adding new map-based function, I discovered, that import

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
```

causes to

*The import com.google cannot be resolved*

Sure, I got the map layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/mapview"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="my_api_key"
             />
```

and added the

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

to manifest file.

So, if this error connected with the wrong target, that I set at the start of creating project, can I fix it - changing Target now, in almost ready app? Or this error is caused by another things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open properties of your application, select android, set build target to your target sdk.

Comment: seems to be, I have no installed Google API target, becouse of I see the only list of Android SDKs

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [mobiForge: Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it causes any issues, it will only bring in additional Google specific functionality and libraries